# Remote app on new iPhone SE won't connect to my Apple Music library on my MacBook Pro

Tags: itunes, home-sharing, remote.app

My old iPhone SE (2nd Gen) would connect to my Apple Music library without a problem.  I replaced it with a new SE (3rd Gen) and now I can't connect to my Apple Music library on my MacBook Pro.

According to the Apple instructions, I need to be on the same wifi network (I am) and be logged into my Apple id on both devices.  (I am.) The iTunes Remote says that no libraries are found.

I clicked on settings and pressed the Add a Media Library button which gives me a code to enter in the Apple Music app.  I successfully enter the code and get a message on the Music app that my remote is now able to control music, but the iPhone app won't do anything.  I get the round icon with the music note but it is greyed out.

I've rebooted, restarted, checked that home sharing is active, etc. but nothing is working.  I upgraded to Ventura 13.3 hoping that might help, but no go.

My old iPhone SE and my iPad Air 2 which will only update to iOS 15.7.4 have no problem connecting to my Apple Music library via the Apple Remote app.  What could be different with my new iPhone SE aside from the newer OS (16.4.1) that is preventing the Apple Remote app from connecting?